# Python console not printing before subprocess is called

Tags: python, terminal

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
for directory in (projects + non_promote_projects):
        os.chdir(directory)
        print_color("Running " + " ".join(ant_command) + " in " + os.getcwd(), "cyan", newline=False)
        print_color(" ... ", "gray", newline=False)

        ant_process = subprocess.call(ant_command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

        if ant_process != 0:
            print_color("Failure!", "red")
            print_color("Error running " + " ".join(ant_command) + " in " + os.getcwd(), "red")
            sys.exit(1)
        else:
            print_color("Success!", "gold")

        os.chdir(current_dir)
```

I am basically just running some ant commands in some directories. The problem is, my first `print_color` statement and the second are not printing before the subprocess is called. I get the feeling there is not enough time for it to print to the console before the subprocess starts. If that's the case how can I ensure it prints before the subprocess call to ant begins?

Comment: It's probably buffering.  One option is that you can call the script with `python -u` to unbuffer.

Comment: Related to the comment above, `newline=False` probably means the result is never flushed. Buffers are often flushed on newline as a compromise between buffering and interactivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm making a guess about your `print_color` function, but you set `newline=False`. Console output is line buffered meaning you either need to send a new line or flush it. Assuming you really do want your print to end a line, change it to `newline=True` (or likely remove that param completely) to get the line.

Comment: You were exactly right about my print color method, it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You need to manually call `sys.stdout.flush()`

```
import sys
import subprocess

sys.stdout.write('\033[1;32;40m111 \033[0m')
sys.stdout.flush() #try comment this line and see the difference
subprocess.call(["sleep","10"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print 222
```